# Trigger - Get all occurence of map in same get

Tags: apex, trigger, map, loop

I have a map map like that and I wanted to know if I could get all the occurrences of my key in one and the same list (without making a loop).

Would you be able to do that?

```
@future
public static void setRepartition(Set<ID> idOpps){

     Map<ID, Map<ID, OpportunityTeamMember>> wrapper = new Map<ID, Map<ID, OpportunityTeamMember>>();
     Map<ID, OpportunityTeamMember> opportunitiesTeamMember = new Map<ID, OpportunityTeamMember>();

     for (ID oppID : idOpps){
          opportunitiesTeamMember =new Map<ID, OpportunityTeamMember>();
          opportunitiesTeamMember = wrapper.get(oppID);

     //code

     }
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now there is no method of map like map.getAll to get all values of map by passing keySet.

Comment: So I have to go through a loop to add as I go along ?

Comment: Yes. the way you are already doing.